# Model.find returns object with wrong ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models:

```
class Miniature < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :minilines, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :lines, :through => :minilines
end

class Line < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :minilines, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :miniatures, :through => :minilines
end

class Miniline < ActiveRecord::Base
    default_scope { select('*').joins(:line).order('lines.name ASC') }
    belongs_to :miniature
    belongs_to :line
end
```

If I try to load a `Miniline` in the Rails console, it returns the wrong object:

```
Miniline.find(206)
Miniline Load (0.3ms) SELECT * FROM "minilines" INNER JOIN "lines" ON "lines"."id" = "minilines"."line_id" WHERE "minilines"."id" = ? ORDER BY lines.name ASC LIMIT 1 [["id", 206]] 
=> #<Miniline id: 16, miniature_id: 183, line_id: 16, created_at: "2014-02-05 16:49:24", updated_at: "2014-04-24 10:37:33">
```

Why?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not identifying the `Miniline` through its own ID? It would be helpful if you could add the relevant parts of the three models to your question (associations etc).

Comment: Hmm. Not that I can remember. Did this ages ago and didn't realise it wasn't working.

Comment: Added models. I think I have to search both Line and Miniature to find the miniline in this case right?

Comment: No, its own ID is sufficient. In your view where you create the `link_to` - are you iterating over a `Miniature`s `mini_lines`, such as `@miniature.mini_lines.each do |miniline|` ?

Comment: No I'm iterating over it's Lines, @miniature.lines.each do |line|

Comment: Then I'd iterate over the `@miniature.minilines` instead, switch the link to `miniline_path(miniline)` and your controller method to the much simpler `Miniline.destroy(params[:id])`. If you are at some line not shown above referring to `line`, change that to `miniline.line` for the same result.

Comment: Have edited to show my full code because I can't get the line names, links etc if I'm iterating through the minilines.

Comment: use `destroy!` instead of `destroy` to show the error

Comment: Just use `miniline.line` in place of `line` to get the same result.

Comment: Ok I've tried changing all my references to lines to miniline.line and they show fine but I can't get the delete working right. Using miniline_path(mini line) it's passing the line id not the miniline id.

Comment: You're always referring to `miniline` as `mini line` (with a space). That makes me a bit suspicious. How _are_ you writing that variable? Also: please hover over one of your delete links. Note the URL and the id from that link. Go into the Rails console, enter `Miniline.find(<id from your delete link>)` and please post both the link and the result from that query.

Comment: The space in miniline is just autocorrect. There is no space. The hover says /minilines/16 (16 matches the Line id !?) In fact if I put miniline.id what I get is the same as miniline.line_id. Confused. Even in console miniline.id is returning the same as miniline.line_id when I can see in the db that that is wrong.

Comment: Should I ask another question? I've got something weird going on here. From my log "2.0.0p247 :005 > Miniline.find(206)
  Miniline Load (0.5ms)  SELECT * FROM "minilines" INNER JOIN "lines" ON "lines"."id" = "minilines"."line_id" WHERE "minilines"."id" = ? ORDER BY lines.name ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 206]]
 => #<Miniline id: 16, miniature_id: 183, line_id: 16, created_at: "2014-02-05 16:49:24", updated_at: "2014-04-24 10:37:33"> 
2.0.0p247 :006 > "

Comment: Why shouldn't they be identical? `Minilines` and `Lines` will have identical ids, as long as you always create them in tandem.

Comment: I don't create them in tandem. Miniline.find(206) brings up the correct miniline but quotes it as being id: 16. I don't understand that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71032/discussion-between-janfoeh-and-ossie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit seems to be the `select('*')` in your

```
default_scope { select('*').joins(:line).order('lines.name ASC') }
```

which is supposed to prevent the `join` in your scope from returning a `ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord`. The canonical way to do this is to use `readonly(false)`:

```
default_scope { joins(:line).order('lines.name ASC').readonly(false) }
```

While [this was buggy](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11199) for a couple of releases, it seems to work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You may have problem in your delete path:  `miniline_path(:miniature_id => @miniature.id, :line_id => line.id)` Check your routes and specify it in your link.

Comment: I do not believe that's correct, as the link does call the correct controller action.